# Can we place an Event Hub in a public subnet in an Azure Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-virtual-network, azure-stream-analytics

Is it possible to add an Event Hub to a VNet in Azure and make it public facing. Is there any restriction that only VMs / Web/API app can be in the public subnet of a VNet and not resources like Event Hub / IoT Hub / Service Bus

Comment: there is no concept of a `public subnet` in azure, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Event hubs by design take public ingress traffic, I believe the only paas service you can add to a VNET is app services, so not event hubs.

Answer (score 1):

An update to this post now is that Azure Virtual network endpoints service is generally available now for the Azure Event hubs. And so you can now use azure event hubs to be inside your vnet and accept traffic only from within your authorized subnets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-service-endpoints